# Ruby recursive decimal to binary method

Tags: ruby, recursion, binary, decimal

I am currently trying to write a method that converts decimal numbers into binary in Ruby. However, it should work without using Ruby's `.to_s(2)` function, and it should be a recursive method instead of a loop. Moreover, the first digit cannot be a 0, but it should start from a 1. Below is the code:

```
def to_binary(d)
  binary = (d % 2).to_s 
  if d == 0
    return binary
  elsif d == 1
    return 1.to_s
  else 
    return binary = binary + to_binary(d/2).to_s
  end
  return binary.to_i
end
```

It seems to get right most of the cases when the first d % 2 actually is 1, but not all of them. How can I remove the first 0's and make it work?

Comment: Notice that you can remove the last statement, as it will never be executed. Also, you don't need any of the `return` keywords. Consider using a `case` statement here: `case d; when 0 then binary; when 1 then "1"; else binary +  to_binary(d/2).to_s; end`.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is correct, you just append the digits in the wrong order. Change the recursive call to this line, and it should work:

```
return binary = to_binary(d/2).to_s + binary
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Would you mind explaining the logic, since shouldn't the first digit be d % 2, then d/2 % 2 and so on.. Now to me it looks like digits are in the opposite order?

Comment: `d % 2` is the last digit.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to convert an integer to the string representation of the number in binary. Another way to write your recursive method is the following.

```
def to_binary(d, str='')
  d.zero? ? str : to_binary(d/2, str.insert(0, (d%2).to_s))
end

to_binary(3)
  #=> "11" 
to_binary(8)
  #=> "1000" 
to_binary(513246)
  #=> "1111101010011011110"
```

If the method needn't be recursive you could use [Fixnum#bit_length](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-bit_length) and [Fixnum#[]](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
def to_binary(d)
  (d.bit_length-1).downto(0).with_object('') { |i,s| s << d[i].to_s }
end
```

You could replace `d%2` with `d[0]` in the recursive method above.